# extracting specific data from a xml file

Tags: python, xml, perl, awk

I have a xml file like this

```
<pr_id>01</pr_id>
    <uniprot>O11482</uniprot>
    <uniprot>O96642</uniprot>
    <uniprot>Q67845</uniprot>
    <column>
        <column_id>1</column_id>
        column_start>300</column_start>
        <column_end>334</column_end>
        <old_new>old</old_new>
        <comment></comment>
    </column>
    <column>
        <column_id>2</column_id>
        <column_start>335</column_start>
        <column_end>337</column_end>
        <old_new>new</old_new>
        <comment></comment>
      <pr_id>02</pr_id>
         <uniprot>P4455</uniprot>
         <uniprot>89WER8</uniprot>
         <uniprot>Q12845</uniprot>
          <column>
        <column_id>1</column_id>
        <column_start>12</column_start>
        <column_end>34</column_end>
        <old_new>old</old_new>
        <comment></comment>
       </column>
        <column>
        <column_id>2</column_id>
        <column_start>35</column_start>
        <column_end>37</column_end>
        <old_new>old</old_new>
        <comment></comment>
```

I would like to get the output as follows.

```
pr_id   uniprot  old_start  old_end
01      O11482   300         334
02      P4455    12          34
02      P4455    35          37
```

What is the easy way to achieve this? This is my first time to deal with xml files. Your valuable suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that the XML is wellformed and then use any XML Parser.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I parse XML in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: Why do you not want output for column no. 2 for `pr_id=01`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gnu Awk version 4, you can use the `split()` function:

```
gawk -f a.awk file.xml
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {RS="^$"}
{
    n=split($0,a,/<\/?(uniprot|pr_id|column_start|column_end|old_new)>/,s)
    for (i=1; i<=n-1;i+=2) {
        if (s[i]=="<pr_id>") {pp=a[i+1]; up=0}
        if (s[i]=="<uniprot>" && up==0) {uu=a[i+1];up=1}
        if (s[i]=="<column_start>") ss=a[i+1]
        if (s[i]=="<column_end>") ee=a[i+1]
        if (s[i]=="<old_new>" && a[i+1]=="old") {
            p[++k]=pp
            u[k]=uu
            s[k]=ss
            e[k]=ee
        }
    }
}
END {
    fmt="%5s%10s%10s%10s\n"
    printf fmt, "pr_id", "uniprot", "old_start", "old_end"
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
        printf fmt,p[i],u[i],s[i],e[i]
}
```

Output:

```
pr_id   uniprot old_start   old_end
   01    O11482       300       334
   02     P4455        12        34
   02     P4455        35        37
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get my desired output. I got the ouput like this  pr_id   uniprot old_start   old_end
                    01    O11482  I use ubuntu12.04 and just installed gawk by using the command sudo dpkg -i gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb.Please help me

Comment: @user3194459 I am also using Ubuntu 12.04. But I am using Gnu Awk version 4.1 (not version 4.0.1), maybe you could try version 4.1 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the XML, but why not use python's minidom for XMLs up to a size of say 30 megs or SAX if you're above that.

Even Excel might do the trick, if you just need it once.

However all this depends on a well formed XML (drag it into a browser, or verify using XML tools of some sort). The XML you posted seems a bit off.